# Displaying daily weather with Dark Sky API

Tags: jquery, weather-api

I'm having trouble getting my weather app working with a 5 day forecast using Dark Sky API. I was able to get the weather to display using "currently" as the key words in my url, but I'm not able to have any information display using "daily" as the key word. I know this was marked as a duplicate, but it is looking for how to display data using JSON (not JSONP) using Dark Sky API so the forecast shows the information for the week and not just for 1 day.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Here's the code I have so far:

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
  <!-- Month and Year -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p id="monthNum"></p>
      <p id="year"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END Month and Year -->

  <!-- Weather Forecast -->
  <div id="weather">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="currentDay" class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail current-thumbnail">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <p class="time text-center"></p>
              <p class="location text-center"></p>
              <p class="tempFeel text-center"></p>
              <p class="humidity text-center"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="text-uppercase text-center"><span class="forecastToday">Thu</span> <br /> <span class="forecastNumToday">14</span></p>
           <p class="icon text-center"></p>
           <p class="temp text-center"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <p class="text-uppercase text-center"><span class="forecastDay">Fri</span> <br /> <span class="forecastNum">15</span></p>
          <p class="icon-upcoming text-center"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <p class="text-uppercase text-center"><span class="forecastDay">Sat</span> <br /> <span class="forecastNum">16</span></p>
          <p class="icon-upcoming text-center"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <p class="text-uppercase text-center"><span class="forecastDay">Sun</span> <br /> <span class="forecastNum">17</span></p>
          <p class="icon-upcoming text-center"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <p class="text-uppercase text-center"><span class="forecastDay">Mon</span> <br /> <span class="forecastNum">18</span></p>
          <p class="icon-upcoming text-center"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END Weather Forecast -->
</div>
```

JS

```
    //Get the user's position
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;

    //Dark Sky API key 
    var apiKey = "API-KEY";

    //Dark Sky URL 
    var weatherURL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";

    //Cross-Origin URL to allow use on Chrome
    var corsURL = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

    //Full Weather Forecast URL
    var fullURL = corsURL + weatherURL + apiKey + "/" + lat + "," + long + "?exclude=currently,hourly,flags";

    //jQuery JSON call to pull in temperature and icon information
    $.getJSON(fullURL, function(json) {

      for (i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
        var temp = json.data.temperatureMax;
        //console.log(temp);
      }
      //Display the Current temp in Farenheit

      //$('.temp').html(temp + "&deg;F");

      var icon = json.daily.icon;
      //console.log(icon);
      $(".icon").html("<i class='wi wi-forecast-io-" + icon +"'></i>");
    });
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? What is the code not doing that you expect it to be doing, or vice versa?

Comment: Are you sure this API doesn't return jsonp instead?

Comment: This isn't the same question as the one being referenced as a duplicate. And the API doesn't return JSONP, it's regular JSON. Here's an example of the JSON data the website provides: [link]https://darksky.net/dev/docs/forecast

I'm attempting to show the weather for the week, not just for the current day, which is what I'm stuck on figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:**

In order to access more than the current weather from the dark sky API use :

```
today = json['daily']['data'][0]['temperatureHigh']
tomorrow = json['daily']['data'][1]['temperatureHigh']
. . .
```

Change the number in the third [] to get each day you want (eg. [4]), it goes from 0 to 7.
In the last [], you can use a keyword to access a different variable from the json ( eg. 'temperatureLow', 'humidity' etc. )

**A little extra:**

Basically the question should be how to access a json file. If you type in your browser url the request ( `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/api_key/lat,lon?units=auto` ). you will get back a huge json string. If you parse it, it should be clear which elements are for what.